# Двойная сортировка MySQL

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Добрый день всем. Столкнулся с задачей необходимо сделать двойную сортировку. Нашел способ.

```
SELECT *
FROM `firms`
ORDER BY `id` ASC, `name` ASC
```

Но вопрос в следующем. Как сделать первую сортировку всего допустим на два элемента. Тоесть допустим есть список городов есть поле позиция Москва и Санкт питербург имеют позицию 1 и 2 остальные позиции не имеют значения нужно сделать так что бы При выводе списком всех позиций из таблицы было следующие сначала выводились бы Москва и Санкт питербург а все остальные значения сортировались по алфавиту. Как можно написать подобный запрос в Mysql

Comment: Простите пожалуйста, уажаемый @alexsis20102, Вы никогда в школе русскому языку не учились? Или, просто, форум не уважаете?

Comment: А вы не понимаете что я пишу ?? или вам необходимо писать со всеми знаками препинания ??? Если вы лично будете решать все задачки которые у меня возникают то специально для вас я буду писать грамотно. По всем правилам великого и могучего. А так уж извините тороплюсь поскорее получить ответ и русский язык меня мало волнует. Меня волнует только решение моей проблемы.

Comment: К сожалению, не только знаки препинания.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так:

```
SELECT *
FROM `cities`
ORDER BY FIELD(`id`,2,1) DESC, `name` ASC
```

1 - Москва, 2 - СПБ, остальные по алфавиту.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте колонку если её нет. Например sort_index с дефолтным значение 0. Все что нужно поднять выше - изменяйте на числа. Больше число - выше позиция. Москве и Питеру ставьте по 1 например. Далее запрос:

```
select * from cities order by sort_index DESC, name ASC
```

А ответ выше явный говнокод. А при добавлении нового условия (например Казань тоже поднять) запросы переписывать пойдете?

Comment: В том то и дело не хотелось переделывать таблицу ))) Но тут либо двумя запросами либо изменением таблице как вы и говорите. На данный момент есть такой столбец в котором указывается позиция. Но она вся уже заполнена значениями. ладно уже сделал двумя запросами ))

Comment: Ну так посмотрите, кто то же её заполнил, значит с какой то целью. Не просто так же кто то сотню строк перелопатил)