# Зафиксировать запись с заданным id в начале выборки

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Есть двухтабличный запрос

```
SELECT w.*, u.name as user
FROM words as w
JOIN users as u ON (u.id = w.user_id)
WHERE w.status = "approved"
ORDER BY w.created_at
LIMIT 5
```

Запрос выбираем слова из базы, добавленные пользователями.
Задача в том, чтобы добавить возможность включения в этот запрос определенной записи по ее `id`.

То есть, сейчас выбираются первые пять записей + для этого запроса предусмотрена постраничная навигация, и позже, когда вызывается следующая страница, меняются значения в `LIMIT`.

Но нужно сделать так, чтобы можно было запись, например с `id = 2`, вывести вместе с первым запросом, и не включать в последующие. Так сделать возможно?

Если плохо объяснил:
По умолчанию все записи должны выводиться так. как выводятся с запросом описанным выше.

Но если добавляется GET-параметр `record_id` в адресной строке, со значением, допустим равным 2, то запись с `id = 2` должна быть включена в запрос, даже если она там не предполагалась.

Comment: допишите к концу своего запроса `union такой-же-select`, но с where id=2, для работы order by возможно подзапрос надо будет заключить в скобки и сделать select * из него

Comment: Как вариант, решение из этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269361/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом, добавить в WHERE-условие конструкцию `OR u.id = 2`, тогда запись с идентификатором 2 гарантировано попадет в выборку. Для того, чтобы эта запись попадала в первый блок, нужно расположить ее в начале результирующей таблицы. Для этого можно модифицировать конструкцию `ORDER BY`, поставив перед столбцом w.created_at динамическое выражение, которое возвращает 0 для записи с u.id = 2 и 1 для всех остальных. В результате запись с u.id = 2 будет зафиксирована в начале результирующей таблицы и будет выведена первой.

```
SELECT
  w.*,
  u.name as user
FROM
  words as w
JOIN
  users as u
ON
  u.id = w.user_id
WHERE
  w.status = "approved" OR
  u.id = 2
ORDER BY
  IF(u.id = 2, 0, 1),
  w.created_at
LIMIT 5
```